# in (jbossfuse) camel Spring XML, can I log before the "from" verb?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

My OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml is the following:

```
--snippet of my blueprint.xml ----
<route id="file2file1">
  <log message="Listening on dir:data/inbox......" />
  <from uri="file:data/inbox"/>
  <to uri="file:data/outbox"/>
--end of snippet --------
```

When I deploy&run my OSGI bundle, JBossFuse log:tail shows this error:

```
...
    2016-03-26 17:54:25,380 | ERROR | edhat-084/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle fuse-demo-blueprint/1.0.0
    org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to validate xml
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.parser.Parser.validate(Parser.java:317)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
...
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'from'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":onException,
...
"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":wireTap, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":restBinding}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)[:]
```

The question: is it possible to insert the "log" tag between "route" and "from" tag?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to insert your log there? A File consumer constantly polls a directory (every half of a second or so by default) and the rest of route only runs when a file is found. If what you are asking was possible, we are looking at a ton of logging. I guess I can help much more if you describe your use case. Regards, R.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that, a route always start with a from.